# Free software for SADT diagrams drawing

Tags: diagrams

Do you know some open source, or just free software to drawing SADT diagrams?

Answer (score 3):

You can try out [Ramus](http://www.ramussoftware.com)

They offer Educational version, free for non-commercial purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The Dia program can do (https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Dia).

Can be used on Linux, Windows and MacOS.